# Questions about poverty

Tags: discussion, scope

Do the questions about poverty belong here, or to the economics stackexchange?

By the questions about poverty I understand the criteria of defining poverty, the discussions and controversies around this criteria, and the statistics about the poverty in particular countries - actual and trends.

Answer (score 2):

This will depend on what the question is asking. It is possible for it to fit on both sites, one of them or neither of them. Don't judge a question solely by the topic of the question, in this case poverty, but the details of what it is asking.

There are plenty of cases where a question would fit on multiple sites and that isn't a bad thing. Though your question should only be posted on a single site even if it fits on multiple ones.